# How to validate absent secrets in the helm chart?

Tags: validation, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am new in kubernetes and helm, but have some task
I need to add validation of secret names and absent secrets.
The first task I have done added next logic to the validation.yaml file in my project :

```
{{- if (not .Values.database.secret) -}}
{{- fail "A valid database secret name .Values.database.secret required!" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

It works when secret name for database in the values.yaml is empty :

```
database:
  secret:
```

But how I can validate that secret is absent?  Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: That should work fine; `.Values.database.secret` will evaluate to `nil`, which is falsey.  What happens if you try it?

Comment: Yes, it works when secret is empty, I get this error. But I need to validate that secret doesn't exist. So, I delete the secret.yaml file and need to get the error  when helm is installing, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What error exactly?  In the case where it fails, is the `database:` container defined in either the chart's `values.yaml` or somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

Helm supports the use of [values.schema.json](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chart-file-structure) to validate the structure of values.yaml such as checking missing key. It is extensible to do far more than simple `if`. No need to re-invent the wheel, here's a well written [tutorial](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/validate-helm-chart-values-with-json-schemas/) to start with.